# Ubuntu 14.04 Active Directory auth fails after static ip config

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, samba, kerberos, winbind

I'm having 6 Ubuntu 14.04 servers that are joined to active directory (2003 domain functional level 2008r2 schema)
All of the servers work's fine when network interface is configured to use DHCP.
But the networks these servers will be located on when they go live dont have any DHCP servers so they HAVE to use static ip config.
I'm using the following PAM config for auth:

```
auth sufficient pam_winbind.so
auth sufficient pam_unix.so nullok_secure use_first_pass
auth required   pam_deny.so
```

/etc/krb5.conf

```
[realms]
    MYDOMAIN.COM = {
    }
[domain_realm]
    .mydomain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM
    mydomain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM
```

and my /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
        security = ads
        realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
        workgroup = MYDOMAIN
        winbind separator = +
        idmap uid = 10000-20000
        idmap gid = 10000-20000
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        template homedir = /home/%D/%U
        template shell = /bin/bash
        client use spnego = yes
        client ntlmv2 auth = yes
        encrypt passwords = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
        restrict anonymous = 2
```

All of this works fine when the servers were configured to use DHCP but now with static ip it no longer works.
I'm no linux expert but I cant even request a kerberos ticket with

```
kinit administrator@MYDOMAIN.COM
```

I get an error saying that it cant locate any kdc, but if I try to specify the kdc in the krb5.conf file i get the following error:

```
kinit kdc reply did not match expectations while getting initial credentials
```

Just leave a comment if you need any more information I may have left out (As earlier mentioned no linux expert) :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add proper forward and reverse entries to Windows domain DNS for all the servers, as Kerberos requires them. It's likely that until now domain DHCP server used to do it automatically, now it doesn't happen due to no DHCP.

Also make sure `/etc/resolv.conf` only lists Windows domain DNS servers.

Comment: Did what you said and listed only Win DNS servers and it worked, thank you a thousand times! :) Don't have enough rep here on serverfault to vote up... sorry :(